# Form input to JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

I'm familiar with JavaScript, but not familiar with using it in the DOM. I'm trying to make a form that will accept an item name + properties and store it like I'm writing out the object below:

```
var grocery_list = {
  "Banana": { category: "produce", price: 5.99 },
  "Chocolate": { category: "candy", price: 2.75 },
  "Wheat Bread": { category: "grains and breads", price: 2.99 }
}
```

Here is the sample HTML Form I have:

```
  <form>
    <input name="item"><br>
    <input name="category"><br>
    <input name="price"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="do stuff">
  </form>
```

How can I use JavaScript take the input above and push it to an Object (like above)?

Comment: You should use a submit listener that gets the values from the inputs, constructs the required object and adds it the the *grocery_list*. Then cancel submit. You could also use a plain button and put the listener on the button.

Comment: @RobG Would that be a JQuery thing?

Comment: No. You *could* use jQuery, but it doesn't add any value here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a listener to the form, collect the values, build an object and add it to the *grocery_list*, e.g.

```
<script>
var grocery_list = {}

function addGroceryItem(form) {
  grocery_list[form.item.value] = {category: form.category.value, price: form.price.value};
  return false;
}
</script>

<form onsubmit="return addGroceryItem(this)">
    <input name="item"><br>
    <input name="category"><br>
    <input name="price"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add item">
    <input type="button" value="Show list" onclick="console.log(grocery_list)">
</form>
```

Though I'd be tempted to use a plain button, not a submit button, and put the listener on the button's *onclick* handler.

Comment: That "fiddle" isn't using my code. This code works in Safari and every browser to IE 6, maybe older (except for the console.log part of course).

Comment: I just popped it in my text editor/HTML file and can see it printing to console.log...thank you!

When I move the script code from the HTML to a separate JS file that I'm linked to, I get grocery_list not defined. Any ideas why?

Comment: No idea, check that *grocery_list* is defined. I've actually tested it in IE 6 on Windows 2000 — aren't VMs wonderful. ;-)

Comment: It is defined in your script, but when I move that script out of the HTML Page and into a linked JS file it seems to errors in console saying that it's not defined :/

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily done with jQuery:

```
var objects = [];
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    var item = $('#item').val(), category = $('#category').val(), price = $('#price').val();
    objects.push({item:{'category':category, 'price':parseFloat(price)}});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(objects));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

By listenting to a `submit` event on the form, populating the object and pushing it to an object array. about reading the values from DOM, see the `$('#input_id').val()` which takes these values.

Assuming you though about pure JS, this could also be done:

```
var objects = [];
var form = document.getElementById('form');
form.onsubmit = function(e){
    var item = document.getElementById('item').value, category =document.getElementById('category').value, price = document.getElementById('price').value;
    objects.push({item:{'category':category, 'price':parseFloat(price)}});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(objects));
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/70fnct9c/

**UPDATE** 
as robg noted, storing the objects in an object instead of array could also be done easily:

```
var objects = {}
................
................
objects[item] = {'category':category, 'price':parseFloat(price)}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/70fnct9c/2/

Comment: Thank you. 
What are these three things doing 
:parseFloat(price); - 
console.log(JSON.stringify(objects)); - 
e.preventDefault();

Comment: `parseFloat` stands for casting string to float (I assumed that you do not want string as a price..) `console.log` is a debugging tool printing values to the console tool (read more about developer tools online), and lastly, `JSON.stringify` converts values into JSON (you do not have to use it in your case, I used it in order to show the output)

Comment: The OP stores the items in an object, not an array.